# Enable/Disable input text com através de loop

Tags: php, jquery

A intenção é, colocar todas as text inputs da variável `VesaoNova` Disable sempre que a text input `VersaoAntiga` está vazia. 
O problema está no jquery nas condições,como resolvo isto?

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

          echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Opcao'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>  <input type='text' name='VersaoAntiga' id= 'VersaoAntiga-".$row['IDOpcao']."' class='form-control'></td>";
            echo "<td>  <input type='text' id='VersaoNova-".$row['IDOpcao']."' name='VersaoNova' class='form-control'></td>";
            echo "<td  style='text-align:center;'><input type='checkbox' name= 'VerificacaoPrevia'></td>";
            echo "<td  style='text-align:center;'>  <input type='checkbox' name='VerificacaoNova'></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";    

            }

            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($conn);
?>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
    var id = e.target.id.split("-");
    $('#VersaoNova-'+id[1]).prop('disabled',true);
    if (id[0]=="VersaoAntiga") {
    $('#VersaoAntiga-'+id[1]).keyup(function(){
    $('#VersaoNova-'+id[1]).prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);     
    })
    }
    }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa atribuir um identificador único para os elementos `VersaoAntiga`, que é o que você vai validar se está vazio para poder desabilitar os outros elementos.

Para isso, adicione um atributo `class` aos inputs e faça o controle em cima do ID. Coloquei o evento `input` atrelado.. e só desabilito o campo de acordo com o ID do `VersaoAntiga`, que foi mais ou menos o que você colocou na pergunta.

```js
$(".versao_antiga").on('input', function(e) {
    var elemento = $(this);
    var idElemento = elemento.attr("id").split('-')[1];

    $("#versaonova-" + idElemento).prop('disabled', elemento.val().length == 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="versaoantiga-1" class="versao_antiga" value="" />
<input type="text" id="versaoantiga-2" class="versao_antiga" value="" />

<input type="text" id="versaonova-1" value="teste" />
<input type="text" id="versaonova-2" value="teste2" />
```

**EDIT:**

Para o seu exemplo em específico, basta editar o seu loop adicionando a `class` mencionada:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

          echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Opcao'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>  <input type='text' name='VersaoAntiga' id= 'VersaoAntiga-".$row['IDOpcao']."' class='form-control versao_antiga'></td>"; #Adicionado 'versao_antiga' à class
            echo "<td>  <input type='text' id='VersaoNova-".$row['IDOpcao']."' name='VersaoNova' class='form-control'></td>";
            echo "<td  style='text-align:center;'><input type='checkbox' name= 'VerificacaoPrevia'></td>";
            echo "<td  style='text-align:center;'>  <input type='checkbox' name='VerificacaoNova'></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";    

            }

            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

E no seu JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(".versao_antiga").on('input', function(e) {
        var elemento = $(this);
        var idElemento = elemento.attr("id").split('-')[1];

        $("#VersaoNova-" + idElemento).prop('disabled', elemento.val().length == 0);
    });
});
```